# Microsoft Access query based on option button

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am building a query in Access. One of the fields [V2] needs to be filtered if an option button on the [Main] form is selected. Right now, I have the following criteria entered for the field.

```
Field:         Expr3: [V2]>0
On Criteria:   IIf([FORMS]![Main]![optV2]<0,True)
```

In the event that the option button is selected, the data is sorted properly. However, in the event that [FORMS]![Main]![optV2] is not <0 (meaning the option button is not selected), I would like all data regardless of [V2] value to be displayed. Currently, no data is displayed if the button is not selected.

Any suggestions on how to do this?
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks,

Lucas

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the `iif` function surrounding your criterion. It needs to look like this:

```
Criteria: [Forms]![Main]![optV2] < 0
```

or like this:

```
Criteria: [Forms]![Main]![optV2] = true
```

The reason your way is not working is you don't specify, in your `iif` function, what value to return if the condition evaluates to false. Strictly speaking, the correct form of your function call would have been:

```
iif([Forms]![Main]![optV2] < 0, true, false)
```

But since the query designer criteria entry field already evaluates the condition, you don't need the `iif` function there at all.